# Facebook Groups - Get email of all members

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For a facebook group admin, is it possible for him to get the name and email of all users in his group using the graph api or any other means? The group has 1000+ members. I can get the list of user's name, id and role using the graph api but not email. I also went through other threads but was not able to get an answer.

Comment: NOTICE EVERYONE - this is a known bug of Facebook. in order to "help" facebook decide to fix it, you should all subscribe to this bug and comment that you need it fixed. here is the bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it´s not possible. But you would not be allowed to use the email in any way, so it would be pointless to retrieve all the emails. You are not even allowed to store it without approval of each user.

Comment: NOTICE EVERYONE - this is a known bug of Facebook. in order to "help" facebook decide to fix it, you should all subscribe to this bug and comment that you need it fixed. here is the bug: developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339

Comment: let's push them a little :) subscribe and comment your thoughts

Comment: "Status: Won't Fix" - since 2014. and honestly, i would be happy if facebook would remove ALL api access to groups.